# Eager loading the last record of an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, associations

I have a model `Invoice` which `has_many Payments` and a model `Payment` that `belongs_to Invoice`.

*Invoice.rb*

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments, inverse_of: :invoice
end
```

*Payment.rb*

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

We export Invoice data monthly in batches, and we need each Invoice's last Payment.

In our view we are currently doing `Invoice.payments.last` once for each Invoice that we are exporting, and I was asked to prevent N+1 queries.

I've tried adding the following associaton to the `Invoice` model:

```
has_one     :last_approved_payment,
              -> { invoice.payments.approved.last },
              class_name: "Payment", inverse_of: :invoice
```

**But I'm getting the following error:**

```
Invoice.first.last_approved_payment
  Invoice Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "invoices"."id", "invoices"."user_id", "invoices"."invoiceable_type", "invoices"."invoiceable_id", "invoices"."status", "invoices"."number", "invoices"."period", "invoices"."external_id", "invoices"."external_status", "invoices"."created_at", "invoices"."updated_at", "invoices"."due_date", "invoices"."metadata", "invoices"."rejection_code", "invoices"."retry_attempt", "invoices"."next_retry_date", "invoices"."last_retry_date", "invoices"."expire_date", "invoices"."external_service", "invoices"."external_type", "invoices"."external_info", "invoices"."account_id", "invoices"."temp_due_date", "invoices"."next_attempt_date", "invoices"."last_attempt_date", "invoices"."processing_stage", "invoices"."amount_cents", "invoices"."amount_currency", "invoices"."desist_retrying" FROM "invoices" ORDER BY "invoices"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Payment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "payments"."id", "payments"."operation_id", "payments"."status", "payments"."status_detail", "payments"."payment_type", "payments"."external_reference", "payments"."payer_email", "payments"."date_created", "payments"."date_approved", "payments"."money_release_date", "payments"."comment", "payments"."created_at", "payments"."updated_at", "payments"."user_id", "payments"."operation_type", "payments"."reason", "payments"."reasonable_type", "payments"."reasonable_id", "payments"."invoice_id", "payments"."metadata", "payments"."account_id", "payments"."amount_cents", "payments"."amount_currency", "payments"."payer_id_ciphertext" FROM "payments" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  Payment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "payments"."id", "payments"."operation_id", "payments"."status", "payments"."status_detail", "payments"."payment_type", "payments"."external_reference", "payments"."payer_email", "payments"."date_created", "payments"."date_approved", "payments"."money_release_date", "payments"."comment", "payments"."created_at", "payments"."updated_at", "payments"."user_id", "payments"."operation_type", "payments"."reason", "payments"."reasonable_type", "payments"."reasonable_id", "payments"."invoice_id", "payments"."metadata", "payments"."account_id", "payments"."amount_cents", "payments"."amount_currency", "payments"."payer_id_ciphertext" FROM "payments" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
**NameError: undefined local variable or method `invoice' for #<Payment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000055b544ccf138>
from /home/vm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:109:in `method_missing'**
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly add a default scope to the model relationship, what you can do is just to preload the `payments` table when retrieving your invoices;

```
Invoice.includes(:payments)
```

Although it'd be better IMO if you just select what you really need from both models, you can achieve that with a subquery using `select`:

```
Invoice.select(
  :id,
  "(SELECT p.id,
    FROM payments p
    WHERE p.invoice_id = invoices.id
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS payment_id"
)
```